# How to display accented characters properly with Perl

Tags: perl

I have a CGI script in Perl. It calls C code to generate anagrams and prints them on the web page:

```
http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=for%C3%AAt%C3%8Ele&language=french&t=5
Fol�tr�e
Fol�tre
E Fol�tr�
F�e Tol�r�
F�e L�rot
```

How do I make sure the resulting web page shows accented characters correctly, irrespective of the web browser encoding?

BTW, the C code shows accented characters correctly when executed on command line on a terminal:

```
Folâtrée
Folâtre
E Folâtré
Fée Toléré
Fée Lérot
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser will set its encoding to whatever you tell it. You do this by including the `charset=UTF-8` response in the HTTP header. (Asusming that you do use UTF-8 and not ISO-8859-1)